# pgAdmin - Too many connection for the role "my username"

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin to connect to my PostgreSQL database. After doing few actions I always get the message of Too many connection for the role "my username".

I have been reading other questions here I have found a solutions that solves the problem but only temporarily and after doing it manually which is closing and deleting the Sessions in the Dashboard in pgAdming like the screen shot below.

[image: Sessions, server activity]

I would like to know either a way of setting my connection limit so I won't get that error or, in case I am mistaking something, a way of fixing anything I am missing out or doing wrong.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the connections permanently. You have to configure `max_connections` parameter.

You can change this in `postgresql.conf` file if postgres is hosted locally.

[Reference for max_connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-connection.html)

[Reference for setting parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/config-setting.html)

Comment: I am using ElephantSQL so I don't have Postgres locally...

Comment: Then you have to increase the database plan in ElephantSQL, because number of max connections depends on the plan you opted.
The same happens with GCP and AWS provider as well

Comment: Wow I didn't know that thank you very much.

In case I would change my plan, how could I configure my max_connections ?

Comment: Your database provider (ElephantSQL) will automatically increase max_connections as soon as you increase the plan along with other database parameters (shared_buffers, work_mem etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much !! You have been very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

when you are locked in do

```
ALTER ROLE my_username CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
```

this would make it so that there is no Limit.

see [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alterrole.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and it gave me the error: 

ERROR:  permission denied
SQL state: 42501

Comment: I have added:

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO my_username WITH GRANT OPTION;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO my_username WITH GRANT OPTION;


But still doesn't work. The owner of Public schema is postgres and when running this query:
ALTER SCHEMA public
    OWNER TO my_username;

It raises an error saying that I have to be owner of public schema to alter that

Comment: are you logging in as postgres (root) ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring... I am connecting to my postgreSQL through my user in pgAdmin